# Why is Trace.WriteLine printing random characters instead of what has been specified?

Tags: c#, .net, coded-ui-tests

I am currently scripting an automated test using Coded UI. I've used Trace.Writeline at various points in my script as an aid to find out where the test may be failing. One such snippet is as follows:

```
Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("Enter press"));
Keyboard.SendKeys("{TAB}");
Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("Tab press x 20"));
Keyboard.SendKeys("{TAB 4}");
Keyboard.SendKeys("{TAB 4}");
Keyboard.SendKeys("{TAB 4}");
Keyboard.SendKeys("{TAB 4}");
Keyboard.SendKeys("{TAB 4}");
Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("Asserting Period cell state."));
```

However when the test is run, I get the following output:

```
2018/01/26 - 15:29:45 | Step 1 
2018/01/26 - 15:30:17 | Step 2 
2018/01/26 - 15:30:54 | Step 3 
2018/01/26 - 15:31:08 | Step 4
2018/01/26 - 15:36:57 | Step 5 
2018/01/26 - 15:42:46 | Step 6
2018/01/26 - 15:42:55 | Step 7 
2018/01/26 - 15:43:04 | Step 10
2018/01/26 - 15:44:46 | Step 11 
EnPer pre46 
Tab pre47 x 20
A47erPinA.D. Perio26 cell 47PaPe.
```

Could someone help me understand why this is happening please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`DateTime.ToString(format)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_) is a method to create a string from a `DateTime`. Parts of the strings you pass are replaced by the time values. For example: the `ss` in `"Asserting..."` is replaced by the seconds.

Change these lines:

```
Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("Tab press x 20"));
```

You probably meant something like

```
Trace.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: Tab press x 20");
```

Comment: Ok, that is very embarrassing! I did intend to write the latter but I have no idea how I missed it.

Comment: @RustyWizard you're welcome, guess most of us had days like that :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "Enter press");
```